# problem with workspaces unity

Tags: workspaces

[image]When I am using a part of the workspace, what happens sometime is that a particular window open in one workspace has its one half in one workspace while the other in some adjacent workspace. This not only makes it very uncomfortable to work with as you have to open workspace switcher again and again to position the window. Is there a solution to it? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

**For 11.10-12.10**

If you click and drag the window and put your mouse against the top taskbar your window should maximise filling exactly one workspace without overlapping on others. As an example if you want to check whether it is working correctly, a typical window maximised window should look like the following:

[image]

If you want windows side by side the same can be done by dragging to window against the left or the right hand side, this way your window will change size to fill up exactly have the current workspace without overlapping on the other workspaces heres another screenshot to clarify:

[image]

Hope this helps, I've never had any issues with this, also when your window is about to maximise you will get an orange outline showing the space that your window will take up once you've let go of the mouse click.

Comment: actually the thing of halving of the windows occur by themself, without any intervention by the user.

Comment: @user1537727 what release are you running? As its worked for me from 11.10-12.04 in exactly the same way, I'd kind of made the assumption the same would apply for 12.10

Comment: am using 12.04.